# Redirect domain URL to subfolder of another domain in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm dummy to php. I want to redirect this link (this one has not it's own hosting)

```
example.com/123456
```

To (this one is parent website with hosting)

```
www.abcd.com/subfolder/123456
```

`123456` is dynamic alphanumeric number.

In sub folder of parent site hosting, there is already an `.htaccess` file which redirects `www.abcd.com/subfolder/123456` to `www.abcd.com/subfolder/index.php?value=123456`

.htaccess file content

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\w+$ index.php?value=$0
```

Anyone know how to redirect url with parameters to another domain's subfolder with same parameters. Thank you.

**Edit:**

I created an new alias for `example.com` and redirected it to `www.abcd.com/example_com` and hosted my index.php to `example_com` directory. Now If I open this link `example.com/?value=123456` it successfully diverts to this link `http://www.abcd.com/example_com/?value=123456`. But If I open `example.com/123456` it says `File not found (404 error)`.

Any idea how to successfully diverts `example.com/123456` to `abcd.com/example_com/?value=123456`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule in site root .htaccess of `example.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ http://abcd.com/subfolder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: your answer seem correct but for that I must have a hosting of example.com which I don't have. Is there anyway I can achieve this with hosting of abcd.com only?

Comment: Unfortunately no. A redirect of `example.com` must be handled on `example.com` itself. Usually a .htaccess is allowed by hosting provider. If you can re-host then point `example.com` to same host as `abcd.com` and use my given rule.

Comment: I'm new web technologies, Can I host example.com to a sub folder of abcd.com? is it possible?

Comment: yes that is also possible or creating an alias (CNAME) for `abcd.com`  as `example.com` is also possible and a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will mark this as correct answer after I check your code. Thanks again.

Comment: I followed your instructions and did what you said. I have edited my question. please have a look. Still my issue is not resolved. I also created .htaccess file having same content you suggested but still no effect. Thanks

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located now? Is it inside `example_com/` directory? Do you have some other rules also in this .htaccess?

Comment: Yes inside example_com/. There is no other rules in .htaccess

Comment: it worked. there was base .htaccess where this code was already written. I changed the last line as per your answer and it worked. Thank you so much.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.abcd\.com\/example_com\/?value=$1" [R=301,L]